# System.InvalidOperationException: This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a trouble on appending new node to xmldocument (created in the memory). I have select the root node with the XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode() method, it work sometimes and in the other time it will give me "System.InvalidOperationException: This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node." error. More information, this xml document is multi level xml document.

By the way, when i try it with unit test it work fine (always), when i implement it in ASP.NET 3.5, it become weird, work sometimes and fail sometimes. Any idea, why this can help? All advise and suggestion are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some code showing how you select and append elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the root node of the XmlDocument using the Property "DocumentElement". Or i think you can use the Property "FirstChild" (untested).

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
XmlElement rootNode = doc.DocumentElement;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It can get the root node, but still throw "System.InvalidOperationException: This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.". Funny thinks is it work sometime and sometime not.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
xmlOriginFile = New XmlDocument()
xmlTargetFile = New XmlDocument()
xmlOriginFile.Load(readFile)  //readFile is a string that hold path to xml document
xmlTargetFile.Load(writeFile) //writeFile is a string that hold path to xml document 

Dim fileNav As XPathNavigator = xmlOriginFile.CreateNavigator()
Dim fileItr As XPathNodeIterator = fileNav.Select("//data")

Dim addToDestNodes As List(Of XmlNode) = New List(Of XmlNode)

While (fileItr.MoveNext())

    Dim addNode As XmlNode = CType(fileItr.Current, IHasXmlNode).GetNode()
    addToDestNodes.Add(addNode)

End While //loop thru nodes

If addToDestNodes.Count > 0 Then

    For Each addedNode As XmlNode In addToDestNodes

        Dim addTargetNode As XmlNode = xmlTargetFile.ImportNode(addedNode, True)
        xmlTargetFile.DocumentElement.AppendChild(addTargetNode)
    Next

End If

xmlTargetFile.Save(xmlTarget) //xmlTarget is a string that hold path to xml document
```

Answer (score 0):

XML has a root element and you have to add new element within this root element.

```
XmlElement eleParent = docDestn.CreateElement("EleParent");
XmlElement eleChild = docDestn.CreateElement("Item");
eleParent.AppendChild(eleChild);
XMLNode rootNode= xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("RootEle");
rootNode.AppendChild(eleParent);
```

Plps. refer the link for detail: http://navinpandit.blogspot.in/2016/12/exception-this-document-already-has.html